# force of usage of generics in Java sources

Tags: java, generics

In Java 6, using generics is optional. Code without generics does compile, but Eclipse takes issue with this, so I started wondering wether in higher Java versions the use of generics may become required, e.g.

```
Collection<?> foo = ...
```

will compile while

```
Collection foo = ...
```

won’t any more. Or: Can the compiler be forced to behave like this?—Something like Perl’s “[use strict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)”?

In other words: Should one expect that work needs to be spent on generifying Java sources currently working fine, but not being equipped with generics? Is there some code backward compatibility guarantee by Oracle or not?

Searching for *force generics* or *java require generics* didn’t lead me to helpful information on that.

Comment: The designers took extra care for backward compatibly via type erasure.  It must be for some valid reason :)

Comment: Found a related one (if not duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697879/javac-flag-to-disallow-raw-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no definitive way to say for sure, but I highly doubt Oracle would both deprecate *and* invalidate a syntax structure. That would be like forcing you to use a diamond inference when it's not truly needed.

I can say with decent certainty that Oracle has no plans to remove syntax from Java. Too many people would complain (as in, almost everything would break).

Answer (score 3):

If raw types were not allowed, you wouldn't be allowed to use old code. However, you can configure Eclipse to generate an error. See in *Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings*, in the section *Generics Types*.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ too warns about use of raw type.  It must be other IDEs as well.  So , I guess, your case for actual build using CI/command line..

You can get compiler warnings `(Xlint:unchecked)` and some post processing.