# Why does the compiler treat List<?> and List<? extends Object> differently?

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class UnboundedWildcardProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<?> a = new ArrayList();
        List<? extends Object> b = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

The creation of `List<?>` doesn't produce any warnings, but the creation of `List<? extends Object>` produces an unchecked warning:

```
Warning: java: unchecked conversion
  required: java.util.List<? extends java.lang.Object>
  found:    java.util.ArrayList
```

I searched for possible reasons and found some discussions:

[List<?> vs List<? extends Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346622/list-vs-list-extends-object)

[What's the difference between <?> and <? extends Object> in Java Generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055389/whats-the-difference-between-and-extends-object-in-java-generics?lq=1)

But after reading these discussions it seems to me that `List<?>` and `List<? extends Object>` are the same thing.

So, what is the reason for such compiler behaviour?

**EDIT:**

The single flag used for compilation was an Xlint:unchecked flag.

Comment: I mean... aren't those different generic declarations? `List<?>` seems different from `List<? extends Object>`

Comment: [Don't use raw types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). This has very little to do with the declared type of `a` and `b`.

Comment: "The creation of List<?> doesn't produce any warnings". Wrong, it does, because "ArrayList is a raw type."

Comment: I dont know if this is true, but shouldnt `? extends Object` exclude Object and provide only objects that extend from it?

Comment: Nope, I am wrong. If a extends b, a is considered to be substitutable for b

Comment: I don't know but the second declaration has a bounds (`extends`) so it might be treated differently internally by the compiler.  The main thing here is "don't use raw types" so that's really the root of the issue here.

Comment: The first snippet DOES produce a warning, contrary to what the OP says.

Comment: The reason is _unchecked conversion_.

Comment: [JLS 5.1.9. Unchecked Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9)

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Are you instructing the compiler to show _all_ warnings using `-Xlint`?

Comment: @manouti i compile with -Xlint:unchecked to show all unchecked warnings.

Comment: Recompile with "-Xlint:rawtypes": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697879/javac-flag-to-disallow-raw-types

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The creation of `List<?>` doesn't produce any warnings, but the creation of `List<? extends Object>` produces an unchecked warning

In fact, if you compile your code with the `-Xlint:all` or just `Xlint` option, you would get a warning for the `List<?> a = new ArrayList();` statement, something like:

```
   warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: ArrayList
            List<?> a = new ArrayList();
                            ^
missing type arguments for generic class ArrayList<E>
where E is a type-variable:
  E extends Object declared in class ArrayList
```

However, the reason why you're not getting an *unchecked warning* per se is because the type `List<?>` contains only unbounded wildcards as mentioned in [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9) from the Java Language Specification:

> There is an unchecked conversion from the raw class or interface type (§4.8) G to any parameterized type of the form `G<T1,...,Tn>`.
>
> ...
>
> **Use of an unchecked conversion causes a compile-time unchecked warning unless all type arguments Ti (1 ≤ i ≤ n) are unbounded wildcards (§4.5.1)**, or the unchecked warning is suppressed by the `SuppressWarnings` annotation (§9.6.4.5).

However in [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1), it is mentioned:

> The wildcard `? extends Object` is equivalent to the unbounded wildcard `?`.

which shows a subtle inconsistency in the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!